# Search different paths for files without asterisk

Tags: search, terminal, path, find

I was wondering.. if I was to look for 5 different files with a similar path.. the five paths to the file of interest being:

`/Users/folder1/exp`

`/Users/folder2/exp`

`/Users/folder3/exp`

`/Users/folder4/exp`

`/Users/folder5/exp`

But I don't want to search for it using an asterisk like so: 
     `find /Users/*/exp`

How can I go about this?